# How do you create a waiting dialog in WIX?

Tags: wix, dialog, modal-dialog, wait

I'm trying to create a dialog to display whilst the installer is checking an SQL server exists.  I've used the following code:

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="244" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">

    <!--Show Waiting dialog-->
    <Publish Property="SQLServerChecked" Value="0">1</Publish>
    <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitCheckSQLServerDlg">
        SQLServerChecked = "1"
     </Publish>

   <!--Checks the SQL server exists-->
   <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CheckSQLServerExists">1</Publish>

   <Publish Property="SQLServerChecked" Value="1">1</Publish>

</Control>
```

However my WaitCheckSQLServerDlg shows, never disappears and the Action CheckSQLServerExists doesn't get run.  How would I alter my code so that the WaitCheckSQLServerDlg displays whilst the CheckSQLServerExists action is running?

Thanks

Comment: It look like someone else has had this problem before and not solved it:
http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg33404.html

Comment: Actually, there was a workaround identified in that thread - the guy just used the existing dialog.  On clicking Next, he hid the existing controls and displayed a "please wait" text box.  Then ran the CA.  Upon return from the CA, showed the next dialog.